# RProtoBuf not loading rprotobuf

Tags: r, protocol-buffers, rcpp

I have installed RProtoBuf successfully but am having an issue when I try and read in .proto files. Below is the session capture of the issue I am having:

```
> library(RProtoBuf)
> proto.dir<-"~/dev/riak_pb/src"
> dir(proto.dir,pattern = "\\.proto$",full.names = TRUE)
[1] "/home/stephen/dev/riak_pb/src/riak_dt.proto"      
[2] "/home/stephen/dev/riak_pb/src/riak_kv.proto"      
[3] "/home/stephen/dev/riak_pb/src/riak.proto"         
[4] "/home/stephen/dev/riak_pb/src/riak_search.proto"  
[5] "/home/stephen/dev/riak_pb/src/riak_ts.proto"      
[6] "/home/stephen/dev/riak_pb/src/riak_yokozuna.proto"

> ls("RProtoBuf:DescriptorPool")
[1] "rexp.CMPLX"                   "rexp.REXP"                   
[3] "rexp.STRING"                  "rprotobuf.HelloWorldRequest" 
[5] "rprotobuf.HelloWorldResponse" "tutorial.AddressBook"        
[7] "tutorial.Person"
```

The dir command seems to say it reads 6 proto files (correct) but there are no corresponding messages in the DescriptorPool.  The read permissions on the .proto files are set as read/write for all.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong gratefully received!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a command to actually *read* the proto files.

Try `readProtoFiles(file=...)` as we do in the unit tests.

Comment: The documentation says you can read a directory of .proto files using the command:    dir(proto.dir,pattern = "\\.proto$",full.names = TRUE) or am I reading that wrongly??

Comment: Where does it say that, what is "the documentation" here?  Can you link to a line form the repo?  I also do not find such a function `dir()` in the `R/` directory.  I *do* however read `.proto` directly as indicated via `readProtoFiles()`.

Comment: I just grep'ed for `proto.dir`. I presume you mean [this whole paragraph](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rprotobuf/blob/master/vignettes/RProtoBuf-intro.Rnw#L106-L153).  It still says to use `readProtoFiles()` and uses `dir()` to _list_ the files.

Comment: It's not very clear looking at "RProtoBuf-intro.pdf" that that is what is meant Dirk.  However loading by reading individual files works, but it does not work for the set-up I have which is 6 .proto files that describe all the Riak messages that are needed.  The set of 6 files are interlinked with imports etc. and can be compiled by protoc but RProtoBuf cannot read them as it throws errors saying that v, y, or z are already loaded by this or that file.  I think I will have to abandon this means of trying to interface R to Riak.

Comment: Yes and it loaded.  I will have to "munge" all the .proto file into one if I continue with this approach.  That's not too much of a hardship though.

Comment: Good to know.  I am still a little mystified why it didn't work for you before.  The package, as I have been told, is in "production use" at a few places known to slashing data around in `.proto` files.    Maybe your issue was particular to these source `.proto` files.

Comment: I suspect it must have been .  TY for the help!

Comment: No worries. Please feel free to "accept" (click on 'tick') and/or "upvote" (click on upward-facing triangle) as that is how the site rolls.